# Разделение приложения на сервисы

Tags: java

Услышал, что современные веб-приложения строятся из независимых сервисов. У меня есть сервер tomcat, java ee и сервер Mysql. Для примера возьмем месседжер. Логически разделим приложения на 3 сервиса: логирование, переписка, поиск пользователя. Я хочу, чтобы они были максимально независимы. Высокая нагрузка на один из сервисов не должна на влиять на другие.Как я понимаю, это своего рода 3 независимых друг от друга приложений. Хотелось бы узнать побольше теории по данной теме и какие технологии для этого используются.

Comment: вы имеете в виду микросервисы?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да

Comment: переформулируйте вопрос, что бы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не придирайтесь к словам. Мне кажется, я понятно изложил суть вопроса, а ошибки в терминологии связаны с отсутствием знаний по данной теме. Вопрос, собственно и задан для приобретения этих знаний.

Comment: СО - это не форум. это сайт ответов на конкретные вопросы. у вас несколько не конкретных вопросов.

Comment: Разделение на микросервисы это архитектурное решение, имеющее свои плюсы и минусы. Не стоит делать что-то только потому, что "это модно/современно". И вообще, по этой теме написаны целые книги, так что если у вас появятся более конкретные вопросы, можете этот вопрос отредактировать, а в текущем виде он подлежит закрытию, как слишком обширный.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про микросервисную архитектуру (Например [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/249183/) и [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/320962/)). Фишка в том что каждый сервис крутится в своей JVM и имеет веб-интерфейс (обычно это REST) или реагирует на JMS-сообщения. Таким образом образуется слабая связь между ними.